# Change Tax according to vendor product on shipping

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add tax functionality according to vendor product and vendors have allowed different shipping address.

I have added the functionality for vendor to select specific tax location and on checkout using this code get tax but unable to update tax after order completed. I am using Dokan multi vendor plugin.

Simply want to add tax on allowed shipping address by vendor.

```
function filter_woocommerce_calc_tax( $taxes, $price, $rates, $price_includes_tax, $suppress_rounding) {    
     global $woocommerce;
     global $wpdb;  
     $subTotal=$woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
     $table = $wpdb->prefix.'tax_state_by_vendor'; 
     $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart(); 
     $reqTaxStat=0;
     $reqTaxStat = $wpdb->get_row("select tax_rate_id from wpyp_woocommerce_tax_rates WHERE tax_rate_country = '".$_REQUEST['s_country']."' and tax_rate_state = '". $_REQUEST['s_state']."'"); 
     $Qunatity=1;

     $productDetails = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach( $cart as $key => $cart_item ){
            $Qunatity += $cart_item['quantity'];
            $post_obj    = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] ); // The WP_Post object
            $productDetails[$i]['product_id'] = $cart_item['product_id'];       
            $productDetails[$i]['vendor_id'] = $post_obj->post_author;  
            $taxes = $wpdb->get_row("select tax_id from $table WHERE vendor_id = ".$post_obj->post_author); 
            $productDetails[$i]['vendor_tax_states'] = $taxes->tax_id;
            $taxDetails = $wpdb->get_results("select wrt.tax_rate,wrt.tax_rate_country,wrt.tax_rate_state from wpyp_tax_state_by_vendor tv left join wpyp_woocommerce_tax_rates wrt on find_in_set(wrt.tax_rate_id, tv.tax_id) > 0
            WHERE tv.vendor_id = ".$post_obj->post_author);

            $productDetails[$i]['vendor_tax_details'] = array();
            foreach($taxDetails as $tkeys => $tval){
                $productDetails[$i]['vendor_tax_details'][$tkeys]['tax_price'] = $tval->tax_rate;
                $productDetails[$i]['vendor_tax_details'][$tkeys]['tax_country'] = $tval->tax_rate_country;
                $productDetails[$i]['vendor_tax_details'][$tkeys]['tax_state'] = $tval->tax_rate_state;
            }
            $productDetails[$i]['product_total_rpice'] = get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'] , '_price', true);
            $i++;
        }
     $totalTax = 0;

     if(!empty($productDetails)){
        foreach($productDetails as $pkey => $pval){
            foreach($pval['vendor_tax_details'] as $taxD){
                if(($_REQUEST['s_country'] == $taxD['tax_country']) && ($_REQUEST['s_state'] == $taxD['tax_state'])){
                     $totalTax += $pval['product_total_rpice'] * $taxD['tax_price'] / 100;
                }
            }
        }
     }
     if(isset($totalTax)){
    // echo $Qunatity;
     // print_r(array($reqTaxStat->tax_rate_id => $totalTax));die;
        return array($reqTaxStat->tax_rate_id => $totalTax * 100 / count($cart));
     } 

    return taxes;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_calc_tax', 'filter_woocommerce_calc_tax', 10, 5);
```

Can anybody help me how will I add tax according to vendor allowed product.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Could you please add some more information, some example of what you mean by Vendor allowed address and Vendor allowed product? How are you trying to change tax after the order has been completed?

Comment: Admin set the tax rule and different vendor want to select few rule out of that where tax will be applied.vendor enabled rule and tax should applied only to there product.

Comment: When we choose the shipping address then according to that tax will applied but the olny thing I wanted is only few rule should be applied here (Custom function where vendor check the few rule out of that)